# pull counts for two hours

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm looking for some help to write a query to find record count for every current two hour window in cosmos and Also i should be able to union all with other table result

For example :-

```
TIme window                count
10:00 AM to 12:00 AM        100
12:00AM TO 2 AM             200
2:00 AM to 4 AM             300
4:00   to 6 AM              400
```

Im using below query

```sql
SELECT count(1) as File_count
     from a where a.file_model = "Log_Type" 
    and a.ingest_time>="2022-05-09T20:00:00" and c.ingest_time <= "2022-05-09T22:00:00"
    union all
SELECT count(1) as SDI_Files_Processed_Count
from a where c.file_model = "Log_Type" 
and a.ingest_time>="2022-05-09T20:00:00" and a.ingest_time <= "2022-05-09T22:00:00" and a.mapr_time!="" and contains(a.fileName,'SDK',true)
```

I know union all is not there in cosmos but that is what im similar expecting in cosmos.

```
Sample Data :- 
ingest_time count
2022-05-09T22:00:00 10
2022-05-09T22:10:00 20
2022-05-09T22:30:00 40
2022-05-09T23:00:00 10
2022-05-09T23:20:00 45
2022-05-09T23:40:00 50
2022-05-09T24:00:00 100
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show your data schema (in your case, the graph model, as you're using Graph API). Without that, there's no way to know how to even begin. Also, include the query you have, along with specific issues. Currently, you've provided only some sample output, with no input data and no work shown.

Comment: Done, Added the query

Comment: Ok, so to be clear: 1) that's not a valid Cosmos DB query, which I know you stated but... it means you haven't tried anything? 2) *please* be sure to add proper formatting - I had already edited your sample output - that should serve as a great example for you to follow; 3) You're showing a SQL API query, but you tagged this as a Gremlin API question (something very different). You *really* need to be specific, both in your question and in your tags. And there still is no input data.

Comment: Have added the sample data.

Comment: This type of query is more suited for something like Azure Stream Analytics using a tumbling window.

Comment: Okay, is there a way i can get the query readymade or let me know how to do it.

Comment: @Never_Give_Up - I suggest starting with the docs for Stream Analytics, to see how windowing queries work. Then, you can post another question showing what you've tried, along with issues you're having.

Comment: Union all doesn't exist because the idea is to force you to denormalize your data instead of having to write complicated, possibly expensive queries for it.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR;

Just do N queries to fetch the minimal required data and move all logic to app.

### Long version

#### Union all

If you feel a need for `union all` then just do 2 queries and merge results in client side as needed. This is simpler, maintainable and just works. Unless you hammer your DB a lot, the cost difference is negligible but you save a lot on implementation/maintenance/RU cost.

If your base query is too RU-consuming then that is a separate and a lot more important problem what you should fix, instead or trying to optimize it with union all.

#### Tumbling window count  - simple

Don't try to put logic into CosmosDB, just use it as fast storage.

Union all out of the way, just query each window count. Unless you already have window start in documents, then the simplest would be just group by the relevant date part, a la :

```
SELECT left(c.ingest_time,13) as "dateToHour", 
    count(1) as "count"    
FROM c
where c.ingest_time between @start and @end
and  .. /* other limiting predicates */
group by left(c.ingest_time,13)
```

In the app side, just merge the hour windows as you need, fill gaps if you care about it, etc.

You could also create [a user-defined function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-udfs) to calc your window start time and make the query return any windows you like.

It may make sense to pre-calculate and include the window times already on ingestion to make it explicit, indexable and avoid datetime operations on each query. Trade some storage for simplicity and speed.

#### Tumbling window count - with window cache

If the RU usage of simple solution is not to your liking you could write the
window counts to cache and reuse them. This cache may even exist in the same CosmosDB database/container. a la:

```
{
    "id" : "guid",
    "type" : "ingestWindow",
    "windowStart" : "2022-05-09T20:00:00",
    "windowEnd" : "2022-05-09T22:00:00",
    "File_Count":  12,
    "WDL_Files_Processed_Count" : 2
}
```

.. or similar. Querying about these windows would become trivial, fast and cheap.

To maintain the cache, you could, for example do a timed trigger (i.e. Function app) to ensure any missing cache entries are created. Or it could be on-request check before the report to keep it out of infra and with your app logic.

Do note that you could also use [change feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/change-feed-design-patterns) to automatically create/update such cache automatically as data/changes come in.

#### Azure Stream Analytics

Is also definitely an option if you see a need for more reporting.

#### Summary

**In CosmosDB, complex queries are costly, but storage is cheap. So it is almost always beneficial to denormalize/cache data to suit your reading needs and move any logic/calculations to your app.**

Comment: I'm running query in the cosmosdb query editor

Comment: In query editor, just make N queries. If N gets large just script a small throw-away program ..

Comment: Can you please help me with UDF function. I want the records counts for tumbling window of two hours. I'm still doing it manual way. I think in the above left join solution still we need to dates manually which is a lot of work.